# Get a list of all currently executing jobs in a cluster with Quartz

Tags: jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

The method Scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs() in quartz apparently is not cluster aware.  What method are people using to get a list of all executing jobs?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like overhauling the scheduling mechanism isn't happening anytime soon.

So, here's how I'm checking the table directly - add group support if you want it:

```
class QuartzClusterJobStatusService
{
    def quartzScheduler

    boolean isJobRunning(String job) {
        return isJobRunningHere(job) || isJobRunningElsewhere(job)
    }

    boolean isJobRunningHere(String job) {
        for (JobExecutionContext j : quartzScheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs()) {
            if (new JobKey(job,"GRAILS_JOBS").equals(j.jobDetail.key)) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    boolean isJobRunningElsewhere(String job) {
        JobStoreSupport js = quartzScheduler.sched.resources.jobStore
        if (!js.isClustered()) {
            return false
        }
        Connection conn = DBConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection(js.getDataSource());
        PreparedStatement stmt = null
        try {
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT 1 FROM " + js.getTablePrefix() + "FIRED_TRIGGERS where JOB_NAME = ?")
            stmt.setString(1, job)
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()
            return rs.next()
        } finally {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would assume one way is to access the database directly, although its a bit risky since the API completely handles that.

There is an issue in their Jira for this purpose. Their conclusion is you need to overhaul the scheduling mechanism if they want to cater cluster aware.

You can refer to http://jira.opensymphony.com/browse/QUARTZ-372